# MySQL migration of table with text var

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I am trying to migrate a MySQL database from an old app to a new one, and there are some tables that contain text variable, like this:

```
id INT
title VARCHAR(255)
description TEXT
```

I am exporting data from the old database into a CSV, using the [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html):

```
SELECT

id, title, description

FROM my_table

INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/my_table.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

And this is a part of the `my_table.csv`:

```
1,"Floriapolis-SC","2 diÃ¡rias para 2 pessoas com late check out de R$ 500 por R$ 199 (final de semana).
"
"
2 diÃ¡rias para 2 pessoas com late check out de R$ 300 por R$ 149 (Check in segunda-feira a quarta-feira).
"
"
3 diÃ¡rias para 2 pessoas com late check out de R$ 450 por R$ 219 (Check in segunda-feira ou terÃ§a-feira).
"
"
4 diÃ¡rias para 2 pessoas com late check out de R$ 600 por R$ 299 (Check in segunda-feira).
"
"
Piscina
"
WIFI
"
Churrasqueira
"
Ãrea de lazer
"
Estacionamento
"
Permitido animais"
2,"Blumenau-SC","CafÃ© da manhÃ£;
"
Cortesia de 02 taÃ§as de vinho;
"
Late Check-out atÃ© as 18hs conforme disponibilidade;
"
LocalizaÃ§Ã£o privilegiada no centro de Canela;
"
Aptos com camas box, calefaÃ§Ã£o, aquecimento de Ã¡gua central, ventilador de teto, frigobar e Internet Wireless."
3,"Gramado-RS","CafÃ© da manhÃ£;
"
Cortesia de 02 taÃ§as de vinho;
"
Late Check-out atÃ© as 18hs conforme disponibilidade;
"
LocalizaÃ§Ã£o privilegiada no centro de Canela;
"
Aptos com camas box, calefaÃ§Ã£o, aquecimento de Ã¡gua central, ventilador de teto, frigobar e Internet Wireless."
```

And then I insert this CSV into the new database.

```
$rows = $this->getCsvToArray('/tmp/my_table.csv');
foreach($rows sd $row){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (id, title, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

But I am getting this error when I migrate the CSV to the new database:

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                               
  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I think that is because the text variable loaded into the CSV file, which has characters like semi comma (;) and double apostrophe ("), and it spoils the data into the CSV file. Maybe when I export the data from old database should be a way to avoid the spolling.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show a part of `my_table.csv`?

Comment: I updated the question, now it has a part of `my_table.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Got to make it work!

First of all, I needed to remove all `"` from `my_table.description`, because those `"` was generating ambiguity with the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` when exporting the table from old database to CSV.

Then, I changed in the MySQL query from `ESCAPED BY '"'` to `ESCAPED BY ''`, like this:

```
SELECT

id, title, description

FROM my_table

INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/my_table.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

Because it was generating ambiguity on double quotes `"` too. And now it works fine.